# Does "2012-05-04T19:36:30.5+00:00" represent UTC time? What would be normalized time in Pakistan?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

This should be fairly simple but I am worst when it comes to time zones. I am getting values from a web service for events generated as following,

- Eastern Turkey: 2012-05-04T19:36:30.5+00:00
- Southern Greece: 2012-05-04T19:33:32.6+00:00
- Poland: 2012-05-04T19:09:36.3+00:00

Do above values represent date time in UTC? (I started with Eastern Turkey but that is +2:00 offset from UTC/GMT and that is making me confused).

My exact problem is that I need to convert above date time to local time zone on WP7 device so is the code below the right approach to do so?

```
//Convert first To UTC Date Time
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind( DateTime.Parse(elementTimeValue.Value),
                                DateTimeKind.Utc);

//Now to local time
convertedDate.ToLocalTime(); << Will this return me with time adjusted to that of operating device (WP7)
```

That's what I am getting for each one of these (while device is in Pakistan),

- 5/4/2012 7:36:30 PM < Eastern Turkey
- 5/4/2012 12:33:32 PM < Southern Greece
- 5/4/2012 12:9:36 PM < Poland

Are these correct? If no, what do I need to do?

Comment: FWIW, these kinds of issues are *exactly* why DateTimeOffset was introduced - to keep people from having to deal with these kinds of things manually. :)

Answer (score 0):

These are **not** UTC times because they have timezone specification even though it's `00:00`. Example of UTC time would be `2012-11-05T13:15:30Z` (not the `Z` at the end). Look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) for more details.

Comment: Timezones like `+00:00` don't follow daylight saving time changes either. For example, British Summer Time is `+01:00`, **not** `+00:00`.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that `+00:00` was always `UTC`?

Comment: So given that all of these have 00:00, how can I normalize this given time to any time zone? Is there a way in C# (silver light, Windows Phone specifically)

Comment: Those times don't have timezone information for some reason and I don't see a way to translate them into another zone. But since they are close to each other maybe they already are translated into one timezone? No idea which one though. Best would be if the web service returned times in UTC always.

Comment: AFAICT the times *do* have timezone information, it's just the zulu/UTC timezone (so, no offset).  offset == 0 is still a valid timezone offset :)

Answer (score 0):

UTC is time zone independant. You just have a date and time stamp, that's it. You would then convert this time stamp to the relevant time zones. So for example to convert it to Eastern Turkey time you would need to add two hours to your time stamp using your operating system's date library.

UTC time zones end in a 'Z' for the offset. The ones you have posted are in Greenwich Mean Time (+00:00). This is similar to UTC in that it has zero offset but not technically the same thing.

**Edit:**  The following web site is really helpful fo confirming if your time zone conversions/date arithmetic is correct (check out the time zone calculators): http://www.timeanddate.com/

For your issue you would need to get the time zone from the user's computer/mobile using *TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone* so that you know what you're trying to convert in to. I think you would be able to do the conversion using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime().

Comment: Thanks, so is there a straight forward way for me to convert the above GMT to normalized time relative to the time zone the user is viewing it?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say UTC is timezone independant - it's just the one that happens to have an offset of 0 from UTC (the others typically are offset by something other than 0 :)    Also, +00:00 is still UTC - the offset is from UTC, so while that is often shown as Z (for zulu/UTC), an offset of 0 from UTC is still UTC.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to the local timezone, by far the easiest approach should be using [DateTimeOffset's Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351654.aspx) and then either just access the [LocalDateTime Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.localdatetime.aspx) (if you only need a DateTime) or convert it with [ToLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tolocaltime.aspx).

Here's an example using one of your strings

```
C:\Users\James » [datetimeoffset]::parse('2012-05-04T19:36:30.5+00:00').tostring()
5/4/2012 7:36:30 PM +00:00
C:\Users\James » [datetimeoffset]::parse('2012-05-04T19:36:30.5+00:00').tolocaltime().tostring()
5/4/2012 3:36:30 PM -04:00
C:\Users\James »
```